# how to calculate years and month from given number c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, timespan

I need to calculate years and months from a given number. how can I do it?
eg:
I am giving: **26**
I need to get result: **2 years 2months**
please help

Comment: What did you tried? Its just simple you need to divide by 12...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some more specific requirements, it should be as easy as Integer Division and the [Remainder operator %](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-)

```
var input = 26;
var years = input / 12;
var months = input % 12;

Console.WriteLine($"{years} years and {months} months");
```

**Output**

```
2 years and 2 months
```

or

```
private static (int Years, int Months) GetYearsAndMonths(int input) 
   => (input / 12, input % 12);

...

var result = GetYearsAndMonths(26);

Console.WriteLine($"{result.Years} years and {result.Months} months");
```

or the little known method [`Math.DivRem Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=net-5.0) as supplied by [@Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface)

> Calculates the quotient of two numbers and also returns the remainder
> in an output parameter.

Comment: Or `var years = Math.DivRem(input, 12, out var months);`

Comment: @Charlieface updated and attributed. I have seen this so many times, and never had a use for it, until now!

Comment: Mainly useful in very tight, high perf loops, because most processors can do this in a single instruction.